# Pinescript takes profit at next candle bar close

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Have I have set levels for a time period and I'm trying to create strategy w/ RSI at these levels, but Pinescript takes profit at next candle bar close.

```
buyzone1 = ta.crossunder(close, b1)
buyzone2 = ta.crossunder(close, b2)
buyzone3 = ta.crossunder(close, b4)
sellzone1 = ta.crossover(close, s1)
sellzone2 = ta.crossover(close, s2)
sellzone3 = ta.crossover(close, s3)

length = input( 14 )
overSold = input( 30 )
overBought = input( 70 )
price = close
vrsi = ta.rsi(price, length)

co = ta.crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu = ta.crossunder(vrsi, overBought)

short_tp = top_valuearea
long_tp = lower_valuearea

short_stp = bottom_tail_value
long_stop = top_tail_value

if (not na(vrsi))
    if (co) and (buyzone1) or (buyzone2) or (buyzone3)
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1 ,comment="Long")
    if (cu) and (sellzone1) or (sellzone2) or (sellzone3)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 1, comment="Short")

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Long TP1", from_entry="Long", limit = long_tp, stop = long_stop)
    strategy.exit("Short TP1", from_entry="Short", limit = short_tp, stop = short_stp)

// Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? long_tp : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Take Profit 1")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? short_tp : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Take Profit 1")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? long_stop : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Stop Loss")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? short_stp : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Stop Loss")
```

But the the the TP is always on the next candle close. Sometimes two Long positions open, and the shorts never take profit.
[image]

I'm not sure why it doesn't follow the RSI logic or take profit at its levels.  The Green dots are the TP1 and the red dots are the stop losses.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `if` check for `strategy.exit`:

```
...
strategy.exit("Long TP1", from_entry="Long", limit = long_tp, stop = long_stop)
strategy.exit("Short TP1", from_entry="Short", limit = short_tp, stop = short_stp)
...
```

Comment: This scratches the trade where the entry and exit are the same position: https://gyazo.com/56a32623ebb9354ce3a76e654fc79612

Comment: Without full code of your strategy I can only guess that problem in long_tp/long_stop and short_tp/short_stp calculations